# Memory leak in Windows Media Foundation MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL function. Any alternative functions?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, ms-media-foundation

On Windows 10 there is bug in Windows Media Foundation function (MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL). It causes memory leak after every use.
Are there any alternative functions to use without memory leak? It seems Windows Media foundation is full of bugs, so how can I avoid it?

Prove of memory leak, run this code (x86) and observe huge memory leak with every second:

```
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "mfuuid.lib")

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (FAILED(MFStartup(MF_VERSION)))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        IMFSourceReader* sourceReader = nullptr;
        if (FAILED(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"C:/any_audio_file.wav", nullptr, &sourceReader)))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        sourceReader->Release();
        MFShutdown();
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Offtopic: So frustated. I was using DirectShow only to discover that there is bug in RenderFile network audio stream. After few days changed to alternative (Windows Media Foundation) and discovered that there is memory leak in there. Microsoft f*** you.

Edit: Memory leak only occurs if filename doesn't have *.mp3 on the end (and content is mp3). Or if filename doesn't have *.wav on the end (and content is wave)
Example:
There is mp3 file "music.mp3". Change name to "music", or to "music.wav". Memory leak will occur.

Comment: _"...Call CoInitialize(Ex) and MFStartup before calling this function...."_: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-mfcreatesourcereaderfromurl

Comment: @RichardCritten: Actually forgot this on stackoverflow answer, but had this in my code. I added it in my answer. Memory leak still exists and is real.

Comment: Who downvoted it? I knew that asking this question on this forum will lead me to black wall, because of its majority users' incompetence

Comment: @c3267738 Please do not offend people who are trying to help you. Downvote mean that the content of your question is deemed not helpful for future viewers but the person who cast a vote. Don't take it personally.

Comment: (1) If you call people offering their time for free names: _"...incompetence ..."_ expect a response.  (2) You provide no statistics for the alleged memory leak and don't explain your methodology. SO posts are supposed to be self-contained with the ability to run code externally a nice to have extra.

Comment: @RichardCritten: my comment was response to downvote, not opposite. This forum would have much better answer quality if reputation system would be removed. Asking question here and getting helpful answer is low probability. But i tried my luck, no success this time.

Comment: @RichardCritten:  Simply running this code will cause huge memory leak on windows 10. I was thinking its better proof than playing with statistics without confirmation.

Comment: I agree. But to fix the question so it fits SO's format all you have to do is to add that information to the question.  Giving the numbers and what tools/methods you used.  Please [ask] specifically the self-contained part of [mcve].

Comment: This code doesn't cause a memory leak on my system.

Comment: @TheTechel: Are you using Windows 10 64 bit?

Comment: Yes. You should really disclose your measurement method.

Comment: @TheTechel: Please remove *.mp3 extension from your file name. I just discovered it now.  Change it to for example to *.wav or no extension. Only then memory leaks occurs

Comment: @TheTechel would be grateful to see your result. Greetings

Comment: I used MSVC's profiler with x64/Release configuration. It stays at ~3MB. The taskmanager doesn't show anything suspicous either.

Comment: Problem seems to occurs only on x86 configuration. Also as I edited in my answer. extension without *.mp3 is the key

Comment: @TheTechel Sorry that I forgot to say that it need to be x86 executable

Comment: Cannot reproduce when compiled as x86 on Windows 10, using the 5MB test wav file from [there](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-wav-download/). [Memory usage](http://wyvup.com/?c=A2tNcPJ) varies as expected, but remains stable overall.

Comment: @Quentin: I downloaded the same file as you, and indeed the memory leak didn't occur, however I changed filename from "file_example_WAV_5MG.wav" to "file_example_WAV_5MG", or from "file_example_WAV_5MG.wav" to "file_example_WAV_5MG.mp3", and memory leak started occuring. So it seems that it occurs if filename extension is different than file content type.

Comment: @c3267738 removing the extension made `MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL` fail immediately, however renaming to `.mp3` did create a leak indeed. Using an actual MP3 file (5M from [here](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-mp3-download/)) seems to also leak, albeit way more slowly.

Comment: @c3267738 I am trying working with other engineer looking into it, any progress will update here. Thanks for reporting this issue.

Comment: @c3267738 Does the code modification in the post fix this issue? Please feel free to let me know if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, you were calling the API **MFShutdown** and **CoUninitialize** mutiple times in one thread. These two APIs should be only called once per thread.

Below is the modified code which match a much more real world usage scenario. You can build this code as **release**(not debug) and run it you will see that there is only a small memory increase (150 kb) over 60 seconds. The small increase is due to an increase in size of the DLL cache (expected) and an increase in the number of work queues being created (expected). So, at this time I don’t see any indication that there is a memory leak.

```
if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED))) // <- Should only be called once per thread
{
    return 1;
}
if (FAILED(MFStartup(MF_VERSION))) // <- Should only be called once per thread
{
    return 1;
}

while (true)
{
    IMFSourceReader* sourceReader = nullptr;

    OutputDebugString(L"MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL \r\n");

    if (FAILED(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"maybe-next-time", nullptr, &sourceReader)))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    sourceReader->Release();

    Sleep(100); // <- Make sure to yield the processor before continuing with the loop 
}

MFShutdown(); // <- Should only be called once per thread
CoUninitialize(); // <- Should only be called once per thread
```

If the memory leak of you side doesn't caused by this, would you mind sharing a code sample which can represent the real word usage?

Comment: Hello. Your code in your post creates memory leak for me. Only the sleep function causes it cummulates slower. Please note that filename is the key for memory leak here. For example, if you have wave file, name it to "test.mp3" or to "test.123456" or to "test". Only then memory leak will occur. If filename will be "test.wav" then memory leak will not occur. I don't know if this memory usage is caused by memory leak or internal caches, but this memory is never released (even after MFShutdown and CoUninitialize), so if program is designed to running long time, this api is completly unusable.

Comment: @c3267738 Are you running the code in release mode? And how much of the memory increased per minute?

Comment: Yes, it's in release mode (x86, on x64 I didn't check). With Sleep(100) it's few megabytes per 10 minutes. But if you run it without sleep, memory increase is instant and visible

Comment: @c3267738 As the comment in the code, to make sure to yield the processor before continuing with the loop, the sleep is necessary for this situation. Is there any real scenario you are developing with for the memory leak issue?

Comment: Yep, Yielding the processor doesn't help in the memory leak. Memory usage is cummulated although slower, because it's run 10 times per second, not 1000 times per second. But with each call memory leak happens. I long time ago, already rejected this broken library, and using 3rd party alternative, without problems. But memory leak is still there in Windows Media Foundation.

Comment: And yes, scenario is real. Audio streaming program that runs 24/7, getting audio data from network, and converting it from mp3 to wav using Windows Media Foundation is not possible, because memory usage will cause it to crash sooner or later.

Answer (score -2):

It is a bug in Microsoft Windows Media Foundation. It was also confirmed in comments.

Solution:

Don't use Microsoft Windows Media Foundation in professional software because it is full of hidden bugs and memory leaks.